# How do I replace div-for or install gem file to allow it to work in Rails 5?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I was doing a tutorial at: https://reinteractive.com/posts/32-ruby-on-rails-3-2-blog-in-15-minutes-step-by-step

and find that I've upgraded to Rails 5 and get an error that div-for has been removed.  It "says" that I can do the following, but:

```
woo-va-air:myapp woo$ gem 'record_tag_helper', '~> 1.0'
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::CommandLineError)
    Unknown command record_tag_helper,
woo-va-air:myapp woo$ ruby --version
ruby 2.3.1p112 (2016-04-26 revision 54768) [x86_64-darwin16]
woo-va-air:myapp woo$ rails --version
/Users/woo/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0/lib/rails/app_loader.rb:40: warning: Insecure world writable dir /Users/woo/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin in PATH, mode 040777
Rails 5.0.0
```

For what I read, the gem 'record_tag_helper' should install that gem, but it fails.  Reading online seems to indicate that it may have been moved somewhere else.

Any ideas on either how to install that gem, or how to rewrite

```
<%= div_for comment do %>
        <p>
                <strong>
                        Posted <%= time_ago_in_words(comment.created_at) %> ago
                </strong>
                <br/>
...
```

So that it works in Rails 5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add

```
gem 'record_tag_helper', '~> 1.0'
```

to your Gemfile and run bundle install

then:

```
require 'record_tag_helper'
```

in application.rb file

Comment: This is promising.  I did this and got no errors when starting server, but still got the error that div-for has been removed in an error message when the comments page, where the div-for was located, was viewed.

Comment: Thanks!  My mistake on the previous comment.  I had to bring the server to the foreground, then quit it and then restart it.  Your solution worked like a charm then.  Appreciate succinct clear instructions like this!

Answer (score 0):

try adding the line

```
gem 'record_tag_helper', '~> 1.0'
```

to `Gemfile`, that you have in your application directory, then run `bundle install`